# Assign GMS Marker to NSMutableArray Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i've successfully shown all my marker from a web service using "for" case, here's my method

```
- (void)setMarker{
double  double_lat;
double  double_long;

for(int i=0;i<[ObjekwisataArray count];i++)
{
    double_lat = [[[ObjekwisataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double_long = [[[ObjekwisataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    GMSMarker *mkr = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    if (double_lat !=0 && double_long!=0)
    {
        [mkr setPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(double_lat, double_long)];
        [mkr setTitle:[[ObjekwisataArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nama"]];
        [mkr setSnippet:@"Kota Ambon"];
        [mkr setMap:NearbyView];
    }

}}
```

now that i want to ask is, how to store my "mkr" variable(GMSMarker) to a NSMutableArray value when all the latitude and longitude has been called, i want my marker to be stored as a NSMutableArray type so i can call it anytime i want. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];

for(int i=0;i<[ObjekwisataArray count];i++)
{
double_lat = [[[ObjekwisataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
double_long = [[[ObjekwisataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
GMSMarker *mkr = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
if (double_lat !=0 && double_long!=0)
{
    [mkr setPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(double_lat, double_long)];
    [mkr setTitle:[[ObjekwisataArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nama"]];
    [mkr setSnippet:@"Kota Ambon"];
    [mkr setMap:NearbyView];
    [arr addObject:mkr];
 }
}}
```

updated!

Comment: yes yes, that's what i mean, where should i place that code? after all the marker has been called and saved in "mkr" value? in my "for" case or outside it? thanks sir